# Show only the most frequest number SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

How do i show only the highest value?
Even if there a tie
So like is there anyway to use MAX COUNT
using sqlLite

```
    SELECT GAMEID,
       COUNT(GAMEID) 

  FROM GAMES
 GROUP BY GAMEID
 ORDER BY COUNT(GAMEID) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect more than one row with the same count, you can use window functions to do this and deal with the ties.

You didn't specify your DBMS product, but the following is 100% ANSI standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT gameid,
           count(*),
           dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    FROM games
    GROUP BY gameid
) t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=869cb70ac8d7f7d10f30329c21783ee7)

Comment: i am using sql lite

Comment: @system21: sqlite supports window functions as well. I updated the online demo to use SQLite

Comment: ok thanks but im still getting syntex error. in relation to ''("

Comment: @system21: no idea. As my link shows, this works without change in SQLite

Comment: @system21 You're probably using an outdated sqlite version that predates window function support.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you're using an outdated sqlite version and can't use window functions, here's another approach that handles ties:

```
WITH counted AS (SELECT gameid, count(gameid) AS count FROM games GROUP BY gameid)
SELECT gameid, count
FROM counted
WHERE count = (SELECT max(count) FROM counted);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add "LIMIT 1" to the end of the query and it will only show one result. However, if 2 entries have the same result it's arbitrary which one will be shown.

Comment: yeah i cant use limit since there is a tie. hence more than one entry

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about ties, then just use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT GAMEID, COUNT(GAMEID) AS CNT
FROM GAMES
GROUP BY GAMEID
ORDER BY COUNT(GAMEID) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to find the games having the highest count, including possible ties, then the `RANK` analytic function provides one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT GAMEID, COUNT(GAMEID) AS CNT, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(GAMEID) DESC) rnk
    FROM GAMES
    GROUP BY GAMEID
)

SELECT GAMEID, CNT
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```